# Simplest way to short two leads with GPIO

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, switching, open-collector

I have a piece of hardware that has an open collector GPIO as shown below:

[image]

I'd like to have use the open-collector output to short two floating wires together -- they're essentially two leads from a button and I want to electronically control the button press.

What's the simplest and most reliable way to do this?  Relays seem way overkill when the current and voltage requirements are almost non-existent -- I just need to be able to selectively short two wires.

A FET solution seems reasonable, though honestly I'm not entirely sure how to go about it as there's no clear way to reference ground (both leads are essentially floating), and I don't know how I'd create the proper V_gs.

What other ideas and solutions could work?

Comment: Consider a Photo-MOS opto isolator.  They are inexpensive and are available as bi-directional.

Comment: What is the button doing when pressen? If it is pulling one wire to ground you yould just connect it directly to your open collector output - if you switch that high, the button "output" would also go to ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate a button press of an external system relays are good solutions as they are galvanically isolated. You can also consider using semiconductor relays. They aren't bulky and also consumes less current. There are also latching relays available which helps you save power too.

If the button is on e the same system sharing common ground,as mentioned in the comment, you can simply connect one end of the switch to the ground or DC and then use the open collector pin to change the switch state.